# python do not follow redirect

Tags: python, redirect, python-requests

I'm trying to get data from https://mobile.bet365.com/sport/default.aspx?ID=200%3a0&key=&ip=1&clvl=&lvl=&t=&bsd=

I have tried:

```
r = requests.get("https://mobile.bet365.com/sport/default.aspx", 
                 allow_redirects=False)
print r.text
```

But I always get redirected to https://mobile.bet365.com/languages.aspx
How to bypass redirect?
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by bypass redirect? 302 header is sent from the server. And you have to send request there again or let request.get do that for you.

Comment: I tried. I always get redirected to languages.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send the accepted language in your request header:

```
headers = {"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5"}
r = requests.get("https://mobile.bet365.com/sport/default.aspx", headers=headers)
print r.text
```